# Does google store the requests that are sent via Google DLP API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I am trying to understand if Google stores text or data that are sent to DLP API? For example, I am having some data (text files) locally and I am planning to use google DLP to help identify sensitive information and maybe transform those back.

Would Google store the text files data that I am using? In other words, would it retain a copy of the files that I am sending? I am trying to read through the security and compliance page, but there is nothing that I could find that clearly explains this.

Could anyone please advise?
Here is what I was looking at https://cloud.google.com/dlp/data-security

Answer (score 2):

Google DLP API only classifies and identifies the kind of data, mostly sensitive, we want to analyse and Google doesn't store the data we send.

Answer (score 1):

We certainly don't store the data being scanned with the *Content api methods beyond what is needed to process it and return a response to you.